# Bootstrap Issue With Nav Pills and Search Bar Expansion Misalignment (Beginner)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mediawiki

I'm using a Mediawiki Bootstrap theme and have managed to center the nav pills.  However, now when you click on the Search button to expand it, the search box moves up a bit.  The site is [here](http://www.nebdat.com).

I tried making the height of the nav pills section bigger as I thought maybe it just couldn't fit, but that didn't help any.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment of the search box is coming from the CSS style

```
@media screen {

.navigation .navbar-search {
display: inline;
float: none;
position: relative;
top: -2.25em;
}
}
```

If you set the top to 0px the alignment looks good to me.